# sqlite select all values with specific id

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

How can I get the results from my table where I can see all the values of a specific id? I am using sqlite3 and python3.

my table:

```
id         value
123        val1
123        val3
123        val2
124        val2
124        val1
```

Result that I want:

```
123          val1, val3, val2
124          val2, val1
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY id
```

Result:

```
(123, 'val1')
(124, 'val2')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
Select * from table where id =123 AND 124
```

Comment: I have multiple ids, so I wont be able to key them all in one by one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `id =123 AND 124` is equivalent to `id = 120`. Who upvoted this?